# Can Charles map incoming request using saved session?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, charles-proxy

In my team, QA will test the application, if there's a bug, QA will record a charles session and provide the file to developer.

Now as a developer, I want to quickly reproduce the bug. Currently what I do is manually save the response, then use the "map local" tool to create a "map local" relationship between the request and response.

But it's tedious and cumbersome if there're multiple requests I need to mock. I'm thinking is it possible just simply tell charles, "hey charles, Use the current recorded session as source, if any future request match one of the recorded request, just use the recorded response. if none request match, let it pass through".

Then when I get a charles session file, it'll be very easy for me the set up the mock response. I can start troubleshooting the bug in just seconds.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your scenario? I facing the same problem

Comment: @eslimaf, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can help but basically, if QAs spot any bugs, they can use the "export flow" feature and then share with you these exported files. When you import such files, you would be able to reproduce quickly without setting up as the request/ response have already been saved.

However the tool I'm using is Proxyman instead of Charles. You can find the detail instruction at
https://proxyman.io/blog/2019/07/How-I-use-Proxyman-to-report-bugs-more-effectively.html. Hope it helps!